# Hide stack frames from certain source files in LLDB

Tags: debugging, lldb

When my program is paused in the debugger using LLDB, I would like to hide stack frames originating from certain source files (or libraries) from appearing in the backtrace. These frames usually correspond to standard library functions that I am not in the process of debugging.

On a similar note, I did find `target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp` which allows me to avoid stepping into select frames. However, I want to also suppress these frames in the backtrace listing, and, avoid showing the same when move up and down the bracktrace.

It seems to be possible to modify the [format of the backtrace](http://lldb.llvm.org/formats.html) but not to conditionally hide certain frames.

Answer (score 0):

There is no facility for doing this in lldb.  Feel free to file a feature request with lldb.llvm.org's bug reporter.

OTOH, it would be quite straightforward to write Python-backed lldb commands that present cooked backtraces like the ones you are suggesting.  The only non-obvious bit is that the way you get the frame-format driven printing for a frame is:

```
ss = lldb.SBStream()
frame.GetDescription(ss)
```

Then you could add the frame to the result object of your command with:

```
result.PutCString(ss.GetData())
```

The only thing that would be pretty difficult to do is to rewrite the frame numbering so that it doesn't show where you've left out frames.  If you just pretended the numbering was different in your output, none of the other lldb commands that take frame numbers would work as expected.  So that wouldn't be a very good idea...  But that's probably a minor deal, and it might actually be nice to see at a glance where missing frames are.